# Get data-attribute value from dynamicly created tabs with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm currently working on a chatsystem that uses jQuery UI tabs for each room and each private chat. Ofcourse these tabs are dynamicly created. Underneath is very simplified example of the way I'm doing this.

```
var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
var ul = tabs.find("#tabs-ul");

$("<li data-user='test'><a href='#test'>test</a></li>").appendTo(ul);
$("<div id='test'></div>").appendTo(tabs);

tabs.tabs("refresh");
```

For the next part, I want to be able to detect the currently selected tab and get the value of the user data-attribute. I will need this to automaticly send the message to the correct room or user. My first idea to accomplish this was the following code:

```
var user = tabs.tabs('option', 'active').data('user');
```

Obviously this wasn't going to work as I'm simply returning the index of the currently selected tab. So what would be the correct way to get the information I need? I've heard something about jQuery UI having a css class that's added to the currently selected tab, in which case the answer would be something like:

```
var user = $("#tabs").find('li.classNameHere').data('user');
```

But I was unable to figure out which class that would be or if it's still working like that or not. Or perhaps it's just getting late and my search skills are failing, haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more research, it turns out the css class name is `ui-tabs-active`. So the correct answer would be:

```
var user = $("#tabs").find('li.ui-tabs-active').data('user');
```